Mongo Queries In C++
The mongo API uses documents (encoded in BSON) as the way to perform queryies (for find / remove etc).
For example a query to find all record where the name field is "John" would look like this (here I will encode the document in JSON for readability but in real life it would be encoded in BSON (which is basically a binary version of JSON).
{
    "name": {
        "$eq": "John"
    }
}

You will notice: The first part is the name of the field "name" then you have the operator "$eq" followed by the value. Note that my serialization library is based on C++ types and will create the appropriate documents automatically if the types are set up correctly. So create the above document I would create following classes:
struct Eq {
   std::string  $eq;     // I know using $ is an extension.
}
struct FindByName {
    Eq          name;
};

Then creating an object would be:
FindByName{{"John"}};

The above example is very trivial version and already requires a doubel braces{{ and }} to initialize. So I wanted to add constructor to make sure we can keep it to one open braces (and deeper nesting don't add up). Side: Note initially I did not use constructors and it became hard to keep track of opening and closing braces without being very careful.
So this would become:
struct Eq {
   std::string  $eq;     // I know using $ is an extension.
}
struct FindByName {
    FindByName(std::string init)
        : name(std::move(init))
    {}
    Eq          name;
};

Since this is a library I don't know the fields names (or the underlying type) as that is part of the application. But the remaining I have created appropriate classes for.
See Member detection within a class  for the the class HasCType.
Meta Interface:
// Check downstream type has a type CType.
template<typename T, bool = HasCType<T>::val>
struct ConstructorType_T;


template<typename T>
struct ConstructorType_T<T, true>
{
    using CType = typename T::CType;
};

template<typename T>
struct ConstructorType_T<T, false>
{
    using CType = T;
};

template<typename T>
using ConstructorType = typename ConstructorType_T<T>::CType;

Use this to get CType from child type. If it is not a query type then it will not have a CType and thus it is a value (as in "John") thus we use the T value. Hopefully it will become clear.
template<typename T>
struct Eq {
    using CType = ConstructorType<T>;
    Eq(CType init): $eq{std::move(init)} {}
    T                  $eq;
};

Then the user of the library would be expected to create their own type following a similar pattern:
template<typename T>
struct FindByName {
    using CType = ConstructorType<T>;
    FindByName(CType init): $eq{std::move(init)} {}
    T                  name;
};

using FindByNameEqual = FindByName<Eq<std::string>>;
using FindByNameLess  = FindByName<Lt<std::string>>;
// etc.

// Construct a query:
auto john   = FindByNameEqual{"John"};
auto Middle = FindByNameLess{"Middle"};

template<typename T>
struct FindByAge {
    using CType = ConstructorType<T>;
    FindByName(CType init): $eq{std::move(init)} {}
    T                  age;
};

using FindByAgeEqual      = FindByAge<Eq<std::uint32_t>>;
using FindByAgeLessEqual  = FindByAge<Lt<std::uint32_t>>;

So the code review
  /*
   * query-comparison
   * https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/
   *      Equal                       => Eq
   *      Not Equal                   => Ne
   *      Greater                     => Gt
   *      Greater or Equal            => Gte
   *      Less                        => Lt
   *      Less or Equal               => Lte
   *      Matches a value in array    => In
   *      Matches no values in array  => Nin
   *
   *          https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/
   *          https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/
   *          https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/
   *          https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/
   *          https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/
   *          https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/
   *          https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/
   */    template<typename T>
  struct Eq {
      using CType = ConstructorType<T>;
      Eq(CType init): $eq{std::move(init)} {}
      T                  $eq;
  };
  // Same pattern for Ne,  Gt, Gte, Lt, Lte (are basically the same as Eq)
  template<typename T>
  struct In
  {
      using CType = std::vector<T>;
      In(CType init): $in{std::move(init)} {}
      std::vector<T>     $in;
  }
  // Same pattern for Nin (is basically the same as In)
  /*
   * query-logical
   * https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query-logical/
   *      Logical AND of two Values           => And
   *      Logical OR  of two Values           => Or
   *      Logical NOR of two Values           => Nor => NOR(A, B) => !(OR(A,B))
   *      Logical NOT                         => Not
   *
   *          https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/and/
   *          https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/or/
   *          https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/nor/
   *          https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/not/
   */
  template<typename LHS, typename RHS>
  struct And
  {
      using CType = And<LHS, RHS>;
      using LP = ConstructorType<LHS>;
      using RP = ConstructorType<RHS>;
      And(LP lhs, RP rhs)
          : $and(std::move(lhs), std::move(rhs))
      {}
      std::tuple<LHS, RHS> $and;
  };
  // Same pattern for Or and Nor
  template<typename T>
  struct Not
  {
      using CType = ConstructorType<T>;
      Not(CType init)
          : $not(std::move(init))
      {}
      T       $not;
  };
  /*
   * query-element
   * https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query-element/
   *      An element exists in the object     =>      Exists
   *          https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/
   *      An element has a specific Type      =>      Type
   *          https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/
   */
  struct Exists
  {
      using CType = bool;
      Exists(bool init)
          : $exists(init)
      {}
      bool   $exists;
  };

  enum class BsonType {   Double = 1,     String = 2,             Object = 3,         Array = 4,
                          BinaryData = 5, ObjectId = 7,           Boolean = 8,        Date = 9,
                          Null = 10,      RegularExpression = 11, JavaScript = 13,    Int32 = 16,
                          Timestamp = 17, Int64 = 18,             Decimal128 = 19,    MinKey = -1,
                          MaxKey = 127
                      };

  struct Type
  {
      using CType = BsonType;
      Type(BsonType type)
          : $type(static_cast<std::int32_t>(type))
      {}
      std::int32_t        $type;
  };
 /*
   * query-evaluation
   * https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query-evaluation/
   *      Mod field and test remainder            =>  Mod
   *          https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/mod/
   *      Regular Expression                      =>  RegEx
   *          https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/
   *      Text search of whole object             =>  Text
   *          https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/text/
   *          Can't seem to get his working.
   *
   */
  struct Mod
  {
      using CType = std::pair<std::uint32_t, std::uint32_t>;
      Mod(CType init)
          : $mod({init.first, init.second})
      {}

      std::array<std::uint32_t, 2>    $mod;
  };
  struct RegEx
  {
      using CType = std::pair<std::string, std::string>;
      RegEx(CType init)
          : $regex(std::move(init.first))
          , $options(std::move(init.second))
      {}

      std::string     $regex;
      std::string     $options;
  };
  struct TextSearch
  {
      std::string                 $search;
      std::optional<std::string>  $language;
      std::optional<bool>         $caseSensitive;
      std::optional<bool>         $diacriticSensitive;
  };
  struct Text
  {
      Text(std::string search, std::optional<std::string> language = {}, std::optional<bool> cs = {}, std::optional<bool> ds = {})
          : $text{std::move(search), std::move(language), std::move(cs), std::move(ds)}
      {}
      TextSearch        $text;
  };
  /*
   * query-array
   *      https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query-array/
   *      Has all the following elements:                                 => All
   *      An array has an element that matches multiple considitions:     => ElemMatch
   *      An array has a specific size:                                   => Size
   *
   *          https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/all/
   *          https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/
   *          https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/size/
   */
  template<typename T>
  struct All
  {
      using CType = std::vector<T>;
      All(CType init)
          : $all(std::move(init))
      {}
      std::vector<T>      $all;
  };
  template<typename T>
  struct Elements
  {
      std::optional<T>    $eq;
      std::optional<T>    $ne;
      std::optional<T>    $gt;
      std::optional<T>    $gte;
      std::optional<T>    $lt;
      std::optional<T>    $lte;
  };
  template<typename T>
  struct ElemMatch
  {
      ElemMatch(std::optional<T> eq, std::optional<T> ne, std::optional<T> gt, std::optional<T> gte, std::optional<T> lt, std::optional<T> lte)
          : $elemMatch{std::move(eq), std::move(ne), std::move(gt), std::move(gte), std::move(lt), std::move(lte)}
      {}
      Elements<T>         $elemMatch;
  };
  struct Size
  {
      using CType = std::uint32_t;
      Size(std::uint32_t init)
          : $size{init}
      {}
      std::uint32_t       $size;
  };
  /*
   * Bitwise Query operator
   *  https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query-bitwise/
   *      AllClear
   *      AllSet
   *      AnyClear
   *      AnySet
   *
   *
   *          https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/bitsAllClear/
   *          https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/bitsAllSet/
   *          https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/bitsAnyClear/
   *          https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/bitsAnySet/
  */
  struct AllClear
  {
      using CType = std::uint32_t;
      AllClear(CType init)
          : $bitsAllClear{std::move(init)}
      {}
      std::uint32_t       $bitsAllClear;
  };
  struct AllSet
  {
      using CType = std::uint32_t;
      AllSet(CType init)
          : $bitsAllSet{std::move(init)}
      {}
      std::uint32_t       $bitsAllSet;
  };
  struct AnyClear
  {
      using CType = std::uint32_t;
      AnyClear(CType init)
          : $bitsAnyClear{std::move(init)}
      {}
      std::uint32_t       $bitsAnyClear;
  };
  struct AnySet
  {
      using CType = std::uint32_t;
      AnySet(CType init)
          : $bitsAnySet{std::move(init)}
      {}
      std::uint32_t       $bitsAnySet;
  };    

Tests:
  TEST(IntegrationConnectionMongoTest, queryEq)
  {
      ThorsMongo          mongo({"localhost", 27017}, {"test", "testPassword", "test"});
      std::vector<People> people{{"Sam", 22, {"Court", "NY", 12}}, {"Sam", 23, {"Jester", "FW", 23}}, {"Sam", 45, {"Limbo", "FG", 56}}};
      using QNameEQ       = Query<FindByName<Eq<std::string>>>;
      using VEQ           = std::vector<QNameEQ>;

      InsertResult        iResult = mongo["test"]["People"].insert(people);
      RemoveResult        r1Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(VEQ{{"Tom"}});
      RemoveResult        r2Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(VEQ{{"Sam"}});

      EXPECT_EQ(1, iResult.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.inserted.size());

      EXPECT_EQ(1, r1Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(0, r1Result.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(1, r2Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, r2Result.n);
  }

  TEST(IntegrationConnectionMongoTest, queryNe)
  {
      ThorsMongo          mongo({"localhost", 27017}, {"test", "testPassword", "test"});
      std::vector<People> people{{"Sam", 22, {"Court", "NY", 12}}, {"Sam", 23, {"Jester", "FW", 23}}, {"Sam", 45, {"Limbo", "FG", 56}}};
      using QNameNE       = Query<FindByName<Ne<std::string>>>;
      using VNE           = std::vector<QNameNE>;

      InsertResult        iResult = mongo["test"]["People"].insert(people);
      RemoveResult        r1Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(VNE{{"Sam"}});
      RemoveResult        r2Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(VNE{{"Tom"}});

      EXPECT_EQ(1, iResult.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.inserted.size());

      EXPECT_EQ(1, r1Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(0, r1Result.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(1, r2Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, r2Result.n);
  }

  TEST(IntegrationConnectionMongoTest, queryGt)
  {
      ThorsMongo          mongo({"localhost", 27017}, {"test", "testPassword", "test"});
      std::vector<People> people{{"Sam", 22, {"Court", "NY", 12}}, {"Sam", 23, {"Jester", "FW", 23}}, {"Sam", 45, {"Limbo", "FG", 56}}};
      using QNameGT       = Query<FindByAge<Gt<int>>>;
      using VGT           = std::vector<QNameGT>;

      InsertResult        iResult = mongo["test"]["People"].insert(people);
      RemoveResult        r1Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(VGT{{56}});
      RemoveResult        r2Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(VGT{{20}});

      EXPECT_EQ(1, iResult.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.inserted.size());

      EXPECT_EQ(1, r1Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(0, r1Result.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(1, r2Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, r2Result.n);
  }

  TEST(IntegrationConnectionMongoTest, queryGte)
  {
      ThorsMongo          mongo({"localhost", 27017}, {"test", "testPassword", "test"});
      std::vector<People> people{{"Sam", 22, {"Court", "NY", 12}}, {"Sam", 23, {"Jester", "FW", 23}}, {"Sam", 45, {"Limbo", "FG", 56}}};
      using QNameGTE      = Query<FindByAge<Gte<int>>>;
      using VGTE          = std::vector<QNameGTE>;

      InsertResult        iResult = mongo["test"]["People"].insert(people);
      RemoveResult        r1Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(VGTE{{57}});
      RemoveResult        r2Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(VGTE{{22}});

      EXPECT_EQ(1, iResult.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.inserted.size());

      EXPECT_EQ(1, r1Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(0, r1Result.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(1, r2Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, r2Result.n);
  }

  TEST(IntegrationConnectionMongoTest, queryLt)
  {
      ThorsMongo          mongo({"localhost", 27017}, {"test", "testPassword", "test"});
      std::vector<People> people{{"Sam", 22, {"Court", "NY", 12}}, {"Sam", 23, {"Jester", "FW", 23}}, {"Sam", 45, {"Limbo", "FG", 56}}};
      using QNameLT       = Query<FindByAge<Lt<int>>>;
      using VLT           = std::vector<QNameLT>;

      InsertResult        iResult = mongo["test"]["People"].insert(people);
      RemoveResult        r1Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(VLT{22});
      RemoveResult        r2Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(VLT{58});

      EXPECT_EQ(1, iResult.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.inserted.size());

      EXPECT_EQ(1, r1Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(0, r1Result.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(1, r2Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, r2Result.n);
  }

  TEST(IntegrationConnectionMongoTest, queryLte)
  {
      ThorsMongo          mongo({"localhost", 27017}, {"test", "testPassword", "test"});
      std::vector<People> people{{"Sam", 22, {"Court", "NY", 12}}, {"Sam", 23, {"Jester", "FW", 23}}, {"Sam", 45, {"Limbo", "FG", 56}}};
      using QNameLTE      = Query<FindByAge<Lte<int>>>;
      using VLTE          = std::vector<QNameLTE>;

      InsertResult        iResult = mongo["test"]["People"].insert(people);
      RemoveResult        r1Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(VLTE{21});
      RemoveResult        r2Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(VLTE{56});

      EXPECT_EQ(1, iResult.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.inserted.size());

      EXPECT_EQ(1, r1Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(0, r1Result.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(1, r2Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, r2Result.n);
  }

  TEST(IntegrationConnectionMongoTest, queryIn)
  {
      ThorsMongo          mongo({"localhost", 27017}, {"test", "testPassword", "test"});
      std::vector<People> people{{"Sam", 22, {"Court", "NY", 12}}, {"Sam", 23, {"Jester", "FW", 23}}, {"Sam", 45, {"Limbo", "FG", 56}}};
      using QNameIN       = Query<FindByAge<In<int>>>;
      using VIN           = std::vector<QNameIN>;

      InsertResult        iResult = mongo["test"]["People"].insert(people);
      RemoveResult        r1Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(VIN{std::vector<int>{25,26,48}});
      RemoveResult        r2Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(VIN{std::vector<int>{23,22,45}});

      EXPECT_EQ(1, iResult.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.inserted.size());

      EXPECT_EQ(1, r1Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(0, r1Result.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(1, r2Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, r2Result.n);
  }

  TEST(IntegrationConnectionMongoTest, queryNin)
  {
      ThorsMongo          mongo({"localhost", 27017}, {"test", "testPassword", "test"});
      std::vector<People> people{{"Sam", 22, {"Court", "NY", 12}}, {"Sam", 23, {"Jester", "FW", 23}}, {"Sam", 45, {"Limbo", "FG", 56}}};
      using QNameNIN      = Query<FindByAge<Nin<int>>>;
      using VNIN          = std::vector<QNameNIN>;

      InsertResult        iResult = mongo["test"]["People"].insert(people);
      RemoveResult        r1Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(VNIN{std::vector<int>{22,23,45}});
      RemoveResult        r2Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(VNIN{std::vector<int>{25,26,48}});

      EXPECT_EQ(1, iResult.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.inserted.size());

      EXPECT_EQ(1, r1Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(0, r1Result.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(1, r2Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, r2Result.n);
  }

  TEST(IntegrationConnectionMongoTest, queryAnd)
  {
      using namespace std::string_literals;

      ThorsMongo          mongo({"localhost", 27017}, {"test", "testPassword", "test"});
      std::vector<People> people{{"Sam", 22, {"Court", "NY", 12}}, {"Sam", 23, {"Jester", "FW", 23}}, {"Sam", 45, {"Limbo", "FG", 56}}};
      using QNameAND      = Query<And<FindByName<std::string>, FindByAge<Lt<int>>>>;

      InsertResult        iResult = mongo["test"]["People"].insert(people);
      RemoveResult        r1Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QNameAND{{"Sam", 23}}));
      RemoveResult        r2Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QNameAND{{"Sam", 58}}));

      EXPECT_EQ(1, iResult.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.inserted.size());

      EXPECT_EQ(1, r1Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(1, r1Result.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(1, r2Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(2, r2Result.n);
  }

  TEST(IntegrationConnectionMongoTest, queryOr)
  {
      using namespace std::string_literals;

      ThorsMongo          mongo({"localhost", 27017}, {"test", "testPassword", "test"});
      std::vector<People> people{{"Sam", 22, {"Court", "NY", 12}}, {"Sam", 23, {"Jester", "FW", 23}}, {"Sam", 45, {"Limbo", "FG", 56}}};
      using QNameOR       = Query<Or<FindByName<std::string>, FindByAge<Lt<int>>>>;

      InsertResult        iResult = mongo["test"]["People"].insert(people);
      RemoveResult        r1Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QNameOR{{"Tom", 23}}));
      RemoveResult        r2Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QNameOR{{"Sam", 18}}));

      EXPECT_EQ(1, iResult.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.inserted.size());

      EXPECT_EQ(1, r1Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(1, r1Result.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(1, r2Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(2, r2Result.n);
  }

  TEST(IntegrationConnectionMongoTest, queryNor)
  {
      using namespace std::string_literals;

      ThorsMongo          mongo({"localhost", 27017}, {"test", "testPassword", "test"});
      std::vector<People> people{{"Sam", 22, {"Court", "NY", 12}}, {"Sam", 23, {"Jester", "FW", 23}}, {"Sam", 45, {"Limbo", "FG", 56}}};
      using QNameNOR      = Query<Nor<FindByName<std::string>, FindByAge<Lt<int>>>>;

      InsertResult        iResult = mongo["test"]["People"].insert(people);
      RemoveResult        r1Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QNameNOR{{"Sam", 22}}));
      RemoveResult        r2Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QNameNOR{{"Tom", 30}}));
      RemoveResult        r3Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QNameNOR{{"Tom", 12}}));

      EXPECT_EQ(1, iResult.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.inserted.size());

      EXPECT_EQ(1, r1Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(0, r1Result.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(1, r2Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(1, r2Result.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(1, r3Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(2, r3Result.n);
  }

  TEST(IntegrationConnectionMongoTest, queryNot)
  {
      using namespace std::string_literals;

      ThorsMongo          mongo({"localhost", 27017}, {"test", "testPassword", "test"});
      std::vector<People> people{{"Sam", 22, {"Court", "NY", 12}}, {"Sam", 23, {"Jester", "FW", 23}}, {"Sam", 45, {"Limbo", "FG", 56}}};
      using QNameNOT       = Query<FindByName<Not<Eq<std::string>>>>;

      InsertResult        iResult = mongo["test"]["People"].insert(people);
      RemoveResult        r1Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QNameNOT{"Sam"}));
      RemoveResult        r2Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QNameNOT{"Tom"}));

      EXPECT_EQ(1, iResult.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.inserted.size());

      EXPECT_EQ(1, r1Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(0, r1Result.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(1, r2Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, r2Result.n);
  }

  TEST(IntegrationConnectionMongoTest, queryExists)
  {
      using namespace std::string_literals;

      ThorsMongo          mongo({"localhost", 27017}, {"test", "testPassword", "test"});
      std::vector<People> people{{"Sam", 22, {"Court", "NY", 12}}, {"Sam", 23, {"Jester", "FW", 23}}, {"Sam", 45, {"Limbo", "FG", 56}}};
      using QNameEXISTS   = Query<FindByName<Exists>>;

      InsertResult        iResult = mongo["test"]["People"].insert(people);
      RemoveResult        r1Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QNameEXISTS{false}));
      RemoveResult        r2Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QNameEXISTS{true}));

      EXPECT_EQ(1, iResult.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.inserted.size());

      EXPECT_EQ(1, r1Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(0, r1Result.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(1, r2Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, r2Result.n);
  }

  TEST(IntegrationConnectionMongoTest, queryType)
  {
      using namespace std::string_literals;

      ThorsMongo          mongo({"localhost", 27017}, {"test", "testPassword", "test"});
      std::vector<People> people{{"Sam", 22, {"Court", "NY", 12}}, {"Sam", 23, {"Jester", "FW", 23}}, {"Sam", 45, {"Limbo", "FG", 56}}};
      using QNameEXISTS   = Query<FindByName<Type>>;

      InsertResult        iResult = mongo["test"]["People"].insert(people);
      RemoveResult        r1Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QNameEXISTS{BsonType::Double}));
      RemoveResult        r2Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QNameEXISTS{BsonType::String}));

      EXPECT_EQ(1, iResult.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.inserted.size());

      EXPECT_EQ(1, r1Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(0, r1Result.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(1, r2Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, r2Result.n);
  }

  TEST(IntegrationConnectionMongoTest, queryMod)
  {
      using namespace std::string_literals;

      ThorsMongo          mongo({"localhost", 27017}, {"test", "testPassword", "test"});
      std::vector<People> people{{"Sam", 25, {"Court", "NY", 12}}, {"Sam", 37, {"Jester", "FW", 23}}, {"Sam", 49, {"Limbo", "FG", 56}}};
      using QNameMod      = Query<FindByAge<Mod>>;

      InsertResult        iResult = mongo["test"]["People"].insert(people);
      RemoveResult        r1Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QNameMod{{12, 0}}));
      RemoveResult        r2Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QNameMod{{12, 1}}));

      EXPECT_EQ(1, iResult.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.inserted.size());

      EXPECT_EQ(1, r1Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(0, r1Result.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(1, r2Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, r2Result.n);
  }

  TEST(IntegrationConnectionMongoTest, queryRegEx)
  {
      using namespace std::string_literals;

      ThorsMongo          mongo({"localhost", 27017}, {"test", "testPassword", "test"});
      std::vector<People> people{{"Samual", 25, {"Court", "NY", 12}}, {"Samantha", 37, {"Jester", "FW", 23}}, {"Samtra", 49, {"Limbo", "FG", 56}}};
      using QNameRegEx    = Query<FindByName<RegEx>>;

      InsertResult        iResult = mongo["test"]["People"].insert(people);
      RemoveResult        r1Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QNameRegEx{{"Samp.*", "i"}}));
      RemoveResult        r2Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QNameRegEx{{"Sam.*", "i"}}));

      EXPECT_EQ(1, iResult.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.inserted.size());

      EXPECT_EQ(1, r1Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(0, r1Result.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(1, r2Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, r2Result.n);
  }

  TEST(IntegrationConnectionMongoTest, queryText)
  {
      using namespace std::string_literals;

      ThorsMongo          mongo({"localhost", 27017}, {"test", "testPassword", "test"});
      std::vector<People> people{{"Sam", 25, {"Cour terror", "NY", 12}}, {"Sam", 37, {"Jes terror", "FW", 23}}, {"Sam", 49, {"Limbo terror", "FG", 56}}};
      using QNameText     = Query<FindByName<Text>>;

      InsertResult        iResult = mongo["test"]["People"].insert(people);
      RemoveResult        r1Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QNameText{{"Anikin"}}));
      RemoveResult        r2Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QNameText{{"Sam"}}));
      RemoveResult        r3Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(Query<FindByName<std::string>>{"Sam"}));

      std::cerr << ThorsAnvil::Serialize::jsonExporter(QNameText{{" Sam "}}) << "\n";

      EXPECT_EQ(1, iResult.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.inserted.size());

      EXPECT_EQ(1, r1Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(0, r1Result.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(1, r2Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, r2Result.n);

      std::cerr << "Cleanup: " << r3Result.ok << " Count: " << r3Result.n << "\n";
  }

  TEST(IntegrationConnectionMongoTest, queryAll)
  {
      using namespace std::string_literals;

      ThorsMongo          mongo({"localhost", 27017}, {"test", "testPassword", "test"});
      std::vector<People> people{
          {"Sam", 25, {"Cour terror",  "NY", 12}, {{10, 13, 14, 15}}},
          {"Sam", 37, {"Jes terror",   "FW", 23}, {{13, 14, 15}}},
          {"Sam", 49, {"Limbo terror", "FG", 56}, {{10, 14, 15}}}
      };
      using QDataAll      = Query<FindByData<All<int>>>;

      InsertResult        iResult = mongo["test"]["People"].insert(people);
      RemoveResult        r1Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QDataAll{{10, 12, 13, 14}}));
      RemoveResult        r2Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QDataAll{{14, 15}}));

      EXPECT_EQ(1, iResult.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.inserted.size());

      EXPECT_EQ(1, r1Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(0, r1Result.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(1, r2Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, r2Result.n);
  }

  TEST(IntegrationConnectionMongoTest, queryElemMatch)
  {
      using namespace std::string_literals;

      ThorsMongo          mongo({"localhost", 27017}, {"test", "testPassword", "test"});
      std::vector<People> people{
          {"Sam", 25, {"Cour terror",  "NY", 12}, {{10, 13, 14, 15}}},
          {"Sam", 37, {"Jes terror",   "FW", 23}, {{13, 14, 15}}},
          {"Sam", 49, {"Limbo terror", "FG", 56}, {{10, 14, 15}}}
      };
      using QDataElemMatch      = Query<FindByData<ElemMatch<int>>>;

      InsertResult        iResult = mongo["test"]["People"].insert(people);
      RemoveResult        r1Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QDataElemMatch{{25, 14, {}, {}, {}, {}}}));
      RemoveResult        r2Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QDataElemMatch{{14, 15, {}, {}, {}, {}}}));

      EXPECT_EQ(1, iResult.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.inserted.size());

      EXPECT_EQ(1, r1Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(0, r1Result.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(1, r2Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, r2Result.n);
  }

  TEST(IntegrationConnectionMongoTest, queryElemSize)
  {
      using namespace std::string_literals;

      ThorsMongo          mongo({"localhost", 27017}, {"test", "testPassword", "test"});
      std::vector<People> people{
          {"Sam", 25, {"Cour terror",  "NY", 12}, {{10, 13, 14}}},
          {"Sam", 37, {"Jes terror",   "FW", 23}, {{13, 14, 15}}},
          {"Sam", 49, {"Limbo terror", "FG", 56}, {{10, 14, 15}}}
      };
      using QDataSize      = Query<FindByData<Size>>;

      InsertResult        iResult = mongo["test"]["People"].insert(people);
      RemoveResult        r1Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QDataSize{2}));
      RemoveResult        r2Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QDataSize{3}));

      EXPECT_EQ(1, iResult.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.inserted.size());

      EXPECT_EQ(1, r1Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(0, r1Result.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(1, r2Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, r2Result.n);
  }

  TEST(IntegrationConnectionMongoTest, queryAllClear)
  {
      using namespace std::string_literals;

      ThorsMongo          mongo({"localhost", 27017}, {"test", "testPassword", "test"});
      std::vector<People> people{{"Sam", 17, {"Cour terror",  "NY", 12}}, {"Sam", 25, {"Jes terror",   "FW", 23}}, {"Sam", 33, {"Limbo terror", "FG", 56}}};
      using QAgeAllClear  = Query<FindByAge<AllClear>>;

      InsertResult        iResult = mongo["test"]["People"].insert(people);
      RemoveResult        r1Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QAgeAllClear{0b11000111}));
      RemoveResult        r2Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QAgeAllClear{0b11000110}));

      EXPECT_EQ(1, iResult.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.inserted.size());

      EXPECT_EQ(1, r1Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(0, r1Result.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(1, r2Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, r2Result.n);
  }

  TEST(IntegrationConnectionMongoTest, queryAllSet)
  {
      using namespace std::string_literals;

      ThorsMongo          mongo({"localhost", 27017}, {"test", "testPassword", "test"});
      std::vector<People> people{{"Sam", 17, {"Cour terror",  "NY", 12}}, {"Sam", 25, {"Jes terror",   "FW", 23}}, {"Sam", 33, {"Limbo terror", "FG", 56}}};
      using QAgeAllSet    = Query<FindByAge<AllSet>>;

      InsertResult        iResult = mongo["test"]["People"].insert(people);
      RemoveResult        r1Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QAgeAllSet{0b00111001}));
      RemoveResult        r2Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QAgeAllSet{0b00000001}));

      EXPECT_EQ(1, iResult.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.inserted.size());

      EXPECT_EQ(1, r1Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(0, r1Result.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(1, r2Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, r2Result.n);
  }

  TEST(IntegrationConnectionMongoTest, queryAnyClear)
  {
      using namespace std::string_literals;

      ThorsMongo          mongo({"localhost", 27017}, {"test", "testPassword", "test"});
      std::vector<People> people{{"Sam", 17, {"Cour terror",  "NY", 12}}, {"Sam", 25, {"Jes terror",   "FW", 23}}, {"Sam", 33, {"Limbo terror", "FG", 56}}};
      using QAgeAnyClear  = Query<FindByAge<AnyClear>>;

      InsertResult        iResult = mongo["test"]["People"].insert(people);
      RemoveResult        r1Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QAgeAnyClear{0b00000001}));
      RemoveResult        r2Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QAgeAnyClear{0b11111110}));

      EXPECT_EQ(1, iResult.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.inserted.size());

      EXPECT_EQ(1, r1Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(0, r1Result.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(1, r2Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, r2Result.n);
  }

  TEST(IntegrationConnectionMongoTest, queryAnySet)
  {
      using namespace std::string_literals;

      ThorsMongo          mongo({"localhost", 27017}, {"test", "testPassword", "test"});
      std::vector<People> people{{"Sam", 17, {"Cour terror",  "NY", 12}}, {"Sam", 25, {"Jes terror",   "FW", 23}}, {"Sam", 33, {"Limbo terror", "FG", 56}}};
      using QAgeAnySet    = Query<FindByAge<AnySet>>;

      InsertResult        iResult = mongo["test"]["People"].insert(people);
      RemoveResult        r1Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QAgeAnySet{0b10000110}));
      RemoveResult        r2Result = mongo["test"]["People"].remove(std::make_tuple(QAgeAnySet{0b11111111}));

      EXPECT_EQ(1, iResult.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, iResult.inserted.size());

      EXPECT_EQ(1, r1Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(0, r1Result.n);
      EXPECT_EQ(1, r2Result.ok);
      EXPECT_EQ(3, r2Result.n);
  }


Don't use $ in identifiers

// I know using $ is an extension.

Then you also know it's not standard C++, and it might stop working at some point in the future. Apart from the compiler, other tools for C++, like code formatters, static analyzers and so on might also not like your use of $.
C++26 added $ to the basic character set, but not to the set of characters that are valid in identifiers, so you still can't use it in C++26. In the future it might even be used as an operator.
So, plenty of reasons to not use it. Find some legal way to encode something in the name such that the BSON serializer will emit a $ where necessary.
Forwarding constructors
When you add a constructor to one class to initialize a member of another type, you have to be a bit careful to avoid inefficiencies. In your FindByName, the constructor takes a std::string by value. While you std::move() it into its final destination, this still has a cost, and it would be better if no moving was necessary at all. You can do this by using perfect forwarding:
struct FindByName {
    template<typename T>
    FindByName(T&& init)
        : name(std::forward<T>(init))
    {}

    Eq name;
};

Using parameter packs, this is easily changed to support constructors that take multiple arguments:
struct Text
{
    template<typename Ts...>
    Text(Ts&&... init)
          : text{std::forward<Ts>(init)...}
    {}
    
    TextSearch text;
};

Using this, I think you don't need CType at all anymore.

Still need the CType because you don't know the value type of Eq as that is user defined. Note it may not be Eq it may be any of the tests (some of the types needed to construct these are not T but vector<T> for example.

Using value in the constructor it catches both rvalue and lvalue reference so I only need one constructor. The string has to be created once and since I always move I get perfect forwarding to the final destination slot no ineffeciency.

Unfortunately the $ is part of the mongo naming convention. I need the dollar there to get the name correct in the underlying object generated.

pass by value + move != perfect forwarding. You are getting inefficiencies with your method, albeit small ones. As for the $, what if Mongo had used * in the naming convention? Then you wouldn't be able to rely on a GCC extension, and you'd have to fix it properly. You can do the same for $. For example, you could write DOLLAR_Eq and have your BSON serializer replace every DOLLAR_ with $. I'm sure there is something more elegant that you could use that still is standards compliant.

This is one of those time I would like the stackoverflow site to have a debate section where we could have a place and go into detail over the technique and argue like I would with a team member on a white board and drill down into both techniques. But looks like I will have to go and and work through both sides and try and validate my way is reasonable :-). I understand the perfect forwarding pattern. But I am taking this from the copy and swap idum where you can use a single assignment operator to cope with both cases (and messing with it to work with constructors).

Yea the Serialization library does already have a technique for solving situations like this (dollar $ and star *). I was deliberately trying to avoid it. But I understand where you are coming from.
